# How to install 12.04 on a pendrive?

Tags: installation, live-usb, bootloader

All I want to do is, install ubuntu onto a pendrive, so that I don't need to use my internal HDD. Another motto is to install packages on Ubuntu, in pendrive(so I don't want to use the 'live pendrive' thing)

I installed it on the pendrive, and selected the boot installation to dev/sdd1.
But when I boot the pendrive, it says '`Missing Operating System`'

Also, one more question, can the same pendrive be booted on any other computer?

Answer (score 2):

To install ubuntu on a external HDD/pendrive(more than 4Gb) you can either use the method explained by @Liang or proceed just as you would for a normal installation but partitioning the pendrive as you would with your internal HDD and choosing to install the bootloader to your pendrive (**not internal hdd**).

Yes, you can boot from any computer which bios allows booting from USB.

I did this 2 years ago with a 32Gb pendrive and I have a couple of advices:

- You should be careful with installing proprietary drivers, they might not be well accepted when you boot from an other computer.
- Be careful with updates. When I was using this, I did some updates that erased my grub from the usb and installed the new version in the internal HDD. I don't remember all the details about this but it messed up all my pendrive, specialy because I didn't know what I was doing when trying to fixed it. So my advice is, if you need updates, remove your internal HDD.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous way to install Ubuntu on a pendrive.
It depends on which platform you are using as your host now.

For windows, visit [this link](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)
and follow the tutorial carefully, it should work for you and it's very simple.

For Ubuntu:
you may simply search "usb creator gtk" in the software center. This package is simple and you should easily complete your task without any help.

For other distribution:
I recommend the tool "live usb install", you may simply Google it.

Comment: Dude, but how do I store my files on the pendrive???

Comment: It's easy and quite the same in the three tools above.For example, in live-usb-install, check the "Persistent documents and settings".Check it out yourself and enjoy it~

Comment: Nope. My files are not getting stored on the pendrive :(

Comment: I'd set the persistent size to 3 GB. My pendrive is 4GB

Comment: REPLY PLEASE :D

Comment: I think t's OK to set the persistent size to 3 GB and it should work. I recommend you using live-usb-install. When you boot the PC from the pendrive, select "Ubuntu ...(Persistent)".

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use a pendrive with at least 30 gb of  memory and use the lili (linux live usb installer) and as for the system it requires about 4,4 gb of memory u will rest with 25,6 gb and all of that u should make it persistent mode so that u could install drivers and make updates to your ubuntu pendrive and using it as another system just by simply conecting it to your pc ,but remember if u don't use the persistant mode u will not be able to use ubuntu as u would like to .

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have a windows ... download ubuntu iso , create ubuntu live cd , put pendrive to usb port ,  boot live ubuntu cd ( test ubuntu)
2. search application: Startup Disk Creator , create usb boot pendrive ,
3. reboot ubuntu , boot from usb